# Type Error: ‘(0, _reactNavigation.StackNavigator)’) is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

Getting Error that reactreactNavigation.StackNavigator is not a function?
I have 4.4.0 version of react navigation installed.
My github is https://github.com/ganiya/ColorfulThrills if you want to see all of the codes
researched but what i've found online doesn't seem to apply to my issue

```js
import React from 'react';
//import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Books from './components/Books';
import Home from './components/Home'


const Navigator = StackNavigator({
   Home:{screen:Home},
   Books: { screen: Books }
 
});
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
     return (
          <Navigator /> 
     );
  }
}
 
export default App;
```

[image: error i'm getting]

Answer (score 0):

You must use `import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'`
Import it from `yarn add react-navigation-stack`